# Do tabs in browsers accept Unicode characters?

Tags: browser, unicode

I want to add a clock icon in the browser tab () through some html/css code. Not as a favicon, but as 'text'

So for example before the word 'Do' without changing the Stackoverflow favicon
[image]

Is this supported by browsers? If yes, how would this look like in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type this into console:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML = ""
```

Its is the `<title>` element that governs the tab title in browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title> Title with clock symbol.</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            The content of the document......
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Okay that works. But what about html/css? How would implement this for a website?

Comment: <title> here is the title <title> Its a html element that usually goes into page <head> element.